# Configure session timeout in webdav Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, webdav, session-timeout

i want to configure Alfresco webdav server in order to logout after 10 minutes from authenification. Do u know please how to do it ?

Comment: Doesn't WebDav send the authentication via HTTP Basic Auth with every new request?

Comment: Thanks for replying, it seems that you did not get the point , i want to say that my documents are accessible via authentification with alfresco dav server , the problem is when a user put jis login and PWD then he still connected till he shut down his browser , then the authentification webdav UI show again , my problem is that i want that every 10 minutes the session close and the user should put his login and pwd again to download files ,

Comment: My point is that I think that the authentication is handled via HTTP basic auth, which isn't session based. You should probably check that, then read up on how http basic auth works / doesn't work

Comment: sorry i m newbie in sush things , how can i check that ?

Comment: You can type in Google something like "How does basic http authentication work", or search stackoverflow for such questions.
But basically, it means that http-auth will ask for credentials on EACH request. So even if you provide login and password to get a document, the user will get the document, but the next time he'll be prompted again. Browsers can work around this, they remember the login credentials, so depending on your use-case, you might or might not prevent this behavior.

Comment: yes it s an http basic authentification , how can i set timeout for the session